# Undefined reference to cblas_ddot when using mkl library

Tags: intel-mkl

I am implementing dot product using cblas_ddot of mkl library.
Command - icc -mmic -o out dot_product.c -lm
error : undefined reference to 'cblas_ddot'

I have included header files of mkl.h and mkl_cblas.h in source code

Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should include  rather than ;
Plus, your error says you are lacking library, you need to tell your compiler which library to link, e.g. -lcblas to link libcblas.a or libcblas.so